# Unable to get created /lastModified and lastRead time of a file

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am trying to access the created / last modified and last accessed DateTime of a file , below is my sample program -

Method signature - `removeFiles(QDir &curDir, QStringList &fileList)`

```
 QString fileName; 
QStringList::Iterator it;
QDateTime fileCreationDate; `

for(it = fileList.begin(); it!= fileList.end(); ++it){
    QFile   currentFile((*it)); 
    QFileInfo currentFileInfo((*it)); 
    fileName = currentFile.fileName(); 

    std::cout<<" "<<fileName.toStdString()<<" creation date is: "<<currentFileInfo.created().toString().toStdString()<<std::endl; 

}
```

`
I am unable to see the created date printed on the screen . Could any one point out the mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does the fileList contain the absolute paths? You should verify that the QFileInfo object is valid. Or is your problem with the output not showing? If this is a windowed application I suggest using qDebug() for debug output instead of cout.

Comment: fileList does not contain absolute path.. Should we have an absolute path?

Comment: Just checked and no, that's not the problem: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfileinfo.html#QFileInfo-2 . Why pass a stringlist in the first place? QDir has an entryList() method that gives you the QFileInfos.

Comment: The entryInfoList() method works fine thanks. Not sure yet why the earlier way of doing things didn't work ..

Comment: It's probably that the list of filenames was erroneous in some way.